# Можно ли повлиять на пул I/O или CPU-bound потоков?

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли повлиять на пул I/O или CPU-bound потоков? Например как с обычным ThreadPool - задать размер пула?

Comment: ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads первым параметром задает пул CPU-bound, а вторым "The maximum number of asynchronous I/O threads in the thread pool", так что получается можно задавать оба, хотя я не понимаю второго зачем им пул вообще.

Comment: @vitidev Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я просто вспомнил про второй параметр метода. У меня нет понимания какое именно влияние он оказывает, только догадки